# simplify regex, [star] mysteriously disappears

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language, computation-theory

[image]!
**Problem**
This is my lecture notes;"Prove a*(b+ab*)=b+aa*b*" 
 I am having trouble understanding what happened at line 3-> line 4;

**What I understand**
Two things happen at those two line;

1. Take `ab*` out of term `ab*` and term `aa*b`, results(Λ+aa*);
2. Last term `aa*ab*` simplifies to `aa*b*` Because a in the middle is redundant;

Question is what happen to the * at `aa*b(*)`?

Comment: What is the carrot?  Is that the standard regex carrot?  If so,
how is /a*/ == /^ +aa*/ == /^\s+aa*/?  I'm confused >.<

Comment: @close vote. Might as well close all reg expression questions like [these1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952629/simplify-this-regular-expression) [these2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859096/simplify-regular-expression-in-mathematica)

Comment: There's probably a better site for CS questions like this.

Comment: @kikuchiyo I think its Λ, which a* can be Λ or aa* because aa* must have at least 1 a.

Comment: @Barmar Then I suggest closing all the tags that aren't directly related to programming. Since there's no code in these theory.

Comment: @wtsang02: `aa*b*` actually got grouped into `(/\+aa*)ab*` and the 3rd term becomes the last term. I close this as too localized.

Comment: @kikuchiyo: Λ denotes [the empty string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string). (In my experience it's usually denoted ε, but Wikipedia says that both λ and Λ are used as well.)

Comment: Is that a photo of a photo on a screen?

Comment: Photo on a screen. Its distance learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your professor left out lines 3⅓ and 3⅔:

```
Line 3:     b + ab* + aa*b + aa*ab*
Line 3⅓:    b + ab* + aa*ab* + aa*b      ←  commute last two terms
Line 3⅔:    b + Λab* + aa*ab* + aa*b     ←  ab* = Λab*
Line 4:     b + (Λ + aa*)ab* + aa*b      ←  distributive property
```

Comment: +1 Even without CS knowledge you can just substitute `Λ` with `1` and apply basic algebra here. ;)